# What is wrong with my variadic-template-based wrapper function?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

I am currently working on a program in which I want to wrap some Vulkan functions in an easier to use variadic template¹. When I attempt to do so, however, I am encountering an error from my compiler (I tried both GCC and clang on Linux with both C++14 and C++17 flags). The following toy example demonstrates the error with similar constructions:

```
#include <iostream>

int exampleFunction(const char *str, int a, int b){ //a const char* is used instead of std::string in order to avoid worrying about the fact that std::string is a class with overridden copying and move semantics
    std::cout << str << ": " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << str << ": " << b << std::endl;
    return a+b; //to avoid non-void return type, as is the case in my real program
}

template<typename T, typename U, typename ... Args>
void functionTemplate(U (*function)(Args...,int,T), Args... args){
    function(args..., 1, 2);
}

int main() {
    functionTemplate(&exampleFunction, "label")
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this program in clang 8.0.1 to the x86_64-pc-linux-gnu target I get the following errors:

```
<path redacted>/main.cpp:15:5: error: no matching function for call to 'functionTemplate'
    functionTemplate(&exampleFunction, "label")
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<path redacted>/main.cpp:10:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'int' against 'const char *'
void functionTemplate(U (*function)(Args...,int,T), Args... args){
```

I expect the program to compile correctly and output the following:

```
label: 1
label: 2
```

Why does this not happen? A good answer will give plenty of theory explaining why, and not just how to fix it. I am asking this question primarily to fix the hole in my C++ knowledge where I don't know why this isn't working. There are alternatives than this style of construction in the real program.

¹: It is possible that the C++ wrapper on Vulkan already does this, but I am using the C API now in order to learn Vulkan better. This issue that I encountered while using the C API shows a gap in my C++ knowledge that I want to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue with

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename ... Args>
void functionTemplate(U (*)(Args..., int, int), Args...);
```

is that `T` is non deducible, you you don't provide it.

Second issue is that deducing rules for variadic template is "limited"
and `Args` isn't deduced as expected for `U (*)(Args..., int, T)`. it is deduced as empty pack (which lead to a non deduced/matching `T`). First `Args` also conflicts with seconds `Args` which is deduced as [`concst char*`].

Comment: That was a typo. I just edited the question to fix it.

Comment: Are you sure that `Args` become empty? I just read the spec, and it seems that `Args` will get all the parameters, and instead `T` will stay undeduced.

Comment: However, there's also a rule that states "A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the parameter-declaration-list." is a non-deduced context. Does this apply here? If so, your initial answer was correct and the suspicion in my comment was incorrect. Does changing to `template<typename ...Args, typename T, typename U>` and calling with `functionTemplate<const char*>(..)` make it compile? If so, we validated that your answer was correct initially, I think.

Comment: I modified it as described ,but I *still* get errors: https://godbolt.org/z/QhdkW4 . Any idea? The error message succests some type mismatch between int and const char*. Huh?

Comment: Alarms off.. I tested on too old compilers. With my modification, it compiles. This supports that your initial answer was correct.